# Mxit integration on iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, mxit

I need Mxit integration for my ios app. Does anyone know how to integrate Mxit with the iOS app like Facebook. I have google it but not found anything.

Comment: Unfortunately at this stage this is not possible as yet. We have at this stage opened up a set of APIs for more information surrounding these please visit: http://dev.mxit.com/docs/